# Is it possible to get common friends of two users using Tweepy?

Tags: python, list, twitter, tweepy, twitter-oauth

I am trying to get mutual friends of two accounts,however it always returns the list of my followers, can anyone suggest, where am i going wrong? any suggestion would be helpful.Thank you.
The code i used is:

```
user1 = input("Please enter 1st twitter user");
user2 = input("Please enter 2nd twitter user");

ids1 = []
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=user1).pages(5):
    ids1.extend(page)
    time.sleep(10)
        
ids2 = []
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=user2).pages(5):
    ids2.extend(page)
    time.sleep(10) 
    
n = 0;
for x in range(0,len(ids1)):
    #print "I came here1";
    for y in range(0,len(ids2)):
        #print "I came here2";
        if(ids1[x] == ids2[y]):
            print (  ids1[x] )
            n =1;
            break;
    
if(n==0):
    print ("No common friends")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it always returns the list of my followers" ?

Comment: when i am running with some other username it still returns the list of followers of my account, as it is a two hierarchy process, first i tried getting my follower list, and from there i tried finding out two users , and if they have anything in common friends between them, but after running the program it still returns the first hierarchy results. i.e, my list of followers.

Comment: I think that you didn't post the relevant part of your code then. We can see neither where you are getting your followers neither where you return anything.